# Digital Input - Cannot display this video mode after writing ubuntu mate on sd card

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, ubuntu-15.04

I have written ubuntu mate image file to sd cared using win32disk manager. When i insert it to raspberry pi, It is displaying "Digital Input - Cannot display this video mode" on the monitor. I am using HDMI Cable and HDMI to VDI converter cable. Please help me out to overcome this .. From last 3 days I am facing this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is geared towards programming questions and not general computing questions like this. You might have better luck at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Replaced HDMI to DVI adapter by HDMI cable and now I can see the 
>   display on the monitor.
>
> 2) You can set the configuration by editing the boot partition on any
>   computer, usually the one you set up the SD card on. read this
>   [documentation](http://%20raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).